# Functions that drop rows that meet conditional

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, function

I'm trying to drop rows from a dataframe that meet the condition of:

if x is between -1 and 1, drop the row and if not continue to loop through the dataframe.

This is for python 2.7 and while I'm not getting any syntax errors, my output file is not recognizing the conditionals embedded into the function when I try to call the function on a specific column within the dataframe. I'm pretty new so there could be multiple issues going on here.

```py
def drop(row):
    counter = 0
    for row in df:
        if row in range(-1,1):
            df.drop(row, axis = 0)
        else:
            continue
        counter =+ 1 

df['column'].apply(drop)
```

Comment: Just index with rows that meet the condition: `df = df[(-1 < df['column']) && (df[column] > 1)]`

Comment: You just need: `df.loc[~df['col'].isin(range(-1,1))]`

Comment: The reason your code isn't doing what you want it to is that `df.drop` does not work in place, unless you tell it to. so, you could use `df.drop(row, axis=0, inplace=True)`. But tbh, harvpan's answer is more efficient.

Comment: @harvpan this should be an answer

Comment: @Marat, good suggestion. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need:

```
df.loc[~df['col'].isin(range(-1,1))]
```

Comment: This does seem a lot more efficient, but for some reason when I execute the script it will not remove the rows with the conditional applied for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you create a [MCVE] for the problem? @D.Larkin

Comment: Please disregard, forgot that range is really designed for integers and not floats. Had to do just a bit of manipulation prior to your suggestion but it seems to be all set now.